# What's the difference between Quaternion subtraction/addition and Quaternion inverse operation?

Tags: c++, animation, math, quaternions

I was reading a document about Additive Animation , which add some animation to another;

The code below demonstrate the algorithm:

```
glm::quat rotDiff = rotQuat2 * glm::inverse(sourceRot);
glm::vec3 posDiff = posVec2 - sourceVec;
auto rotQuat = rotQuat1* rotDiff;
auto posVec = posVec1 + posDiff;
```

rotDiff is the rotation which should be added to origin animation;
The rotDiff is calculated with `rotQuat2 * glm::inverse(sourceRot)`, this is One line I don't fully understand,
The third line  `rotQuat = rotQuat1 * rotDiff` is the another I don't fully understand.

If I were write this algorithm, I would like to  `rotDiff = rotQuat2 - sourceRot`
`rotQuat = rotQuat1 + rotDiff`, ie, use subtraction instead of multiply the inverse of sourceRot, use addition instead of multiplication, because this is intuitive.

Could you please explain the difference ?

The quaternion class is like this [https://cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/quaternion.h](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Eacoates/quaternion.h)

Comment: If you intend to concatenate 3d transformations, you can do this by multiplying the corresponding 4x4 matrices. (Please, note: _multiplying_ not _adding_) Why? Because the multiplication of matrices results in the intended effect of "chaining transformations" while addition would just produce number garbage concerning this. This is how the math works... (I used 4x4 matrices as analogy as quaternions are even harder to understand IMHO.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat But why Quaternion class provide operator+ and operator- ? what are they used for?

Comment: I must admit I hadn't any idea but I found a similar question in gamedev: [Is adding quaternions a useful operation?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/121026/126706) ;-) As I understood it it's similar like with land maps: Actually we're walking on a sphere but for short distances, you can pretend it's a plane and use Euclidean geometry which is actually not appropriate for a sphere surface.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two different quaternions Q1 and Q2. You can multiply Q1 times other quaternion, lets say Qx, to obtain the quaternion Q2. This can be written in a equation like:

Q2 = Qx Q1

How can you find Qx? The answer is multiplying both sides by the inverse of Q1 so

Q2 Q1^-1 = Qx Q1 Q1^-1

Q2 Q1^-1 = Qx

In some sense Qx is the "multiplicative" difference between Q1 and Q2.

Why multiplication instead of substraction? The reason is: rotation (in general) is applied to vectors using multiplication, not addition, like R v. When you apply succesive rotations to a vector you are multiplying it with rotations several times, like R2 (R1 v). Since matrix multiplication (and quaternion multiplication) is associative, you can combine succesive rotations like (R2 R1) v

Is quaternion addition useful at all? The answer is YES!! When you want to interpolate quaternions you essentially perform a weighted sum of them. Actually you can average quaternions by just adding them and then normalizing, you will obtain a valid quaternion.